# Why does accessing the element next to the given position misbehave, whereas accessing the previous element works correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, implicit-conversion

Given the following simple piece of Javascript code:

```
var a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

for ( var i in a ) {
    console.log(a[i-1], a[i], a[i+1]);
}
```

why does it produce the strange output below?

```
undefined 1 undefined
1 2 undefined
2 3 undefined
```

The first `undefined` on the first line and the last `undefined` on the last line are because of out-of-bounds accesses. But where do the other two `undefined`'s come from?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the two other questions. It is as much about implicit conversions as it is about iterating over arrays. The problem of `i-1` working correctly while `i+1` not, has to do with how Javascript chooses to do conversions in mixed expressions, and as pointed out in my answer you can have a similar problem even without arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly modified test case very well exposes the problem:

```
$ cat test.js 
var a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

for ( var i in a ) {
    console.log(i-1, i, i+1);
    console.log(a[i-1], a[i], a[i+1]);
    console.log('--------');
}

$ nodejs test.js 
-1 '0' '01'
undefined 1 undefined
--------
0 '1' '11'
1 2 undefined
--------
1 '2' '21'
2 3 undefined
--------
```

So, the variable `i` is of **string type**. When using it to access the previous element, Javascript being a weakly typed language, the interpreter figures out that the expression `i-1` makes sense only if `i` is converted to a number. To keep things fair (and programmers' lives interesting), in the expression `i+1` the interpreter converts `1` to a string and treats `+` as concatenation, producing a key that is missing from the array (or, if the array were long enough, a wrong element would be accessed: `a[11]` instead of `a[2]`, `a[21]` instead of `a[3]`, etc).

In this particular case the problem comes from the incorrect way of looping over the array (if the answer to this question was not obvious to you then carefully read the [excellent explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/6394138) of [how to iterate over arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9329446/6394138)). However it can bite you in any other situation where a variable that is supposed to be numeric actually holds a string value (for example, when parsing text data and forgetting to do the conversions).